# How to separate attributes from a NSAttributed String and apply these attributes on other string?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, swift2

eg. Like we have a NSAttributed string and we need to separate string and attributes, then use these attributes on other string of same length.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your expected input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An NSAttributedString may have different attributes for different ranges of the string.

To extract these attributes, you can use the `enumerateAttributesInRange` method.

We prepare an array of tuples to hold the results:

```
var extractedAttributes = [(attributes: [String:AnyObject], range: NSRange)]()
```

Each tuple will hold the attributes for a specific range in the NSAttributedString.

Now we iterate on the NSAttributedString and populate the array with the results:

```
attributedString.enumerateAttributesInRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0)) { (dict, range, stopEnumerating) in
    extractedAttributes.append((attributes: dict, range: range))
}
```

Once the array is populated, you can access the contents:

```
for item in extractedAttributes {
    print(item.attributes)
    print(item.range)
}
```

And from there you have all you need to create new attributed strings with these attributes: you have the range and the corresponding attributes for each one in the NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this method from NSAttributedString

```
attributesAtIndex(location: Int, effectiveRange range: NSRangePointer) -> [String : AnyObject]
```

By calling this method at NSAttributedString you will receive all attributes applied in range. Just specify all string as range. And then create new attributes string with these attributes.